# how to call javascript function on asp dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to load a dropdown with numbers 1 - 20 and I have a javascript code to perform this. But Not sure how this function has to be called in the dropdown list.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
quantitydropdown();
})

function quantitydropdown()
{
  // Get reference to drop down
  var ddl = document.getElementById('quantitydropdownid');

  for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    var theOption = document.createElement("option");
    theOption.text = i;
    theOption.value = i;
    // If it is the first option, make it be selected
    i === 1 ? theOption.selected = "selected" :  "";
    ddl.options[i] = theOption;
  }
}
```

```css
#quantitydropdownid { width:200px; }

#quantitydropdownid option:empty
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="quantitydropdown">Quantity</label>
<select id="quantitydropdownid" runat="server"></select>
```

So I am not sure how I should call this javascript function into the dropdown list. Need help!!

Comment: Do you need to load number on page load?

Comment: your code works fine you just needed to add jquery to your page

Comment: @Jainil yes I need to load numbers on load and want to select one number from the list. Also I am trying to link this script with the asp dropdown list control

Comment: @chiller you have edited the code but the dropdown is not working fine. The value is not getting selected

Comment: @VDWWD No its not a duplicate question. I want to link the javascript function with the control.

Comment: @Akansha its because you are calling the quantitydropdown function onchange, i edited the code, take a look.

Comment: @chiller Thanks! that's working. But how do I link the function quantitydropdown() to the asp control quantitydropdownid ? Means, when I include this code under the script tag and the select control under body tag, I am not able to link the function.

Comment: @Akansha you need to link the js file with the function in the asp page just like i linked jquery.js or you can add the js code inside a script tag inside the asp page